# PostGis insert Rectangle

Tags: sql, geospatial, postgis, spatial-index, spatial-query

Hi all i have a question:
how i can insert a box (rectangle) with Ne_latitude, NE_longitude, SW_latitude, SW_longitude inside a postgis database and build an INDEX on top for retrieving the intersection between the different boxes?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [ST_MakeEnvelope](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/ST_MakeEnvelope.html) to build a rectangle geometry. It can be used to retrieve the intersection of bounding boxes from `some_table` (with geometry column `geom`) using the [`&&` overlaps operator](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/geometry_overlaps.html):

```
SELECT *
FROM some_table
WHERE geom && ST_MakeEnvelope(SW_longitude, SW_latitude, NE_longitude, NE_latitude, 4326);
```

---

To insert the rectangle into `some_table`:

```
INSERT INTO some_table (geom)
VALUES (ST_MakeEnvelope(SW_longitude, SW_latitude, NE_longitude, NE_latitude, 4326));
```

and in case `some_table` does not yet have a spatial index on the `geom` column, [create it](http://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#gist_indexes):

```
CREATE INDEX ON some_table USING gist (geog);
```

Comment: thanks but how i can insert a rectangle inside a db and build an index??